# How can I combine a 2D list plot with a 3D list plot?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to combine `ListPointPlot` and `ListPointPlot3D` together using `Show`. Unfortunately, `Show` does the plot, but displays the default views.

```
data1 = Table[Sin[2*x], {x, -2, 2, 0.1}];
data2 = Table[Sin[2*x] + Cos[4*y] + Sin[x*y], {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, {y, -2, 2, 0.1}];

figure1 = ListPlot[data1, Joined->True]
figure2 = ListPlot3D[data2, Mesh->None]
```

This is the code I thought might trick show into doing what I want. I am attempting to plot 2D and 3D together by placing the 2D plot as a layer on top of the 3D plot

```
figure4 = 
  ListPlot[data1, Joined -> True, ViewPoint -> Top, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5}]
figure5 = 
  ListPlot3D[data2, Mesh -> None, ViewPoint -> Right, BoxRatios ->{0.01, 1, 1}]
Show[figure4, figure5]
```

Unfortunately, this method does not work. The result shows that I have to rotate Table of data1 such that the values of z-x axis are in y-x.  Transpose works in z-x and z-y axis but not in y-x axis (for data1). How do I fix that?

Notes:

1. The data's are for illustration purpose only. The original are too complicated.
2. Mathematica v.9

Comment: you mean something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PqLdI.png) or [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/M1ybP.png)?

Comment: .. or [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rRjYJ.png)?

Comment: I'd convert them both to 3D graphics primitives and display them exactly as you like in `Graphics3D`.

Comment: @kglr, Your asked like this (1) or this (2) or this(3).....More like (2) and (3) with transparent background of sin.

Comment: Aschoolar, posted the code that produced (3) as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
figure1 = ListPlot[data1, Joined->True,  PlotStyle-> {Thick, Red}, DataRange->{-2, 2}];
figure1b =  Graphics3D[{figure1[[1]] /. Line[x_] :> Line[ArrayPad[x, {{0}, {0, 1}}, 3]]}];
figure2 = ListPlot3D[data2, Mesh -> None, DataRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}];

Show[figure1b, figure2, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: ,Can you please give some clue on how to manipulate ranges and rotation.  In my actual data for 3D, Show works only if figure2 DataRange is set in Automatic mode

Comment: @Aschoolar, could you post a small example your actual data?